# Problem with C# HTTP PUT request code

Tags: c#, http, web

I am trying to send a file to S3 via a PUT request URL that Amazon S3 has already generated for me.

My code works fine for small files, but it errors out on large files (>100 mb) after a few minutes of sending.

There error is: ***The request was aborted: The request was canceled.    at System.Net.ConnectStream.InternalWrite(Boolean async, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)***

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with my code that is stopping it from sending large files?  It is not due to the Amazon PUT request URL expiring because I have that set to 30 minutes and the problem occurs after just a few minutes of sending.

The code eventually exceptions out on this line of code: `dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);`

Once again, it works great for smaller files that I am sending to S3.  Just not large files.

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(PUT_URL_FINAL[0]);
//PUT_URL_FINAL IS THE PRE-SIGNED AMAZON S3 URL THAT I AM SENDING THE FILE TO

request.Timeout = 360000; //6 minutes

request.Method = "PUT";

//result3 is the filename that I am sending                                     
request.ContentType =
    MimeType(GlobalClass.AppDir + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "unzip" +
             Path.DirectorySeparatorChar +
             System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(result3));

byte[] byteArray =
    File.ReadAllBytes(
        GlobalClass.AppDir + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "unzip" +
        Path.DirectorySeparatorChar +
        System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(result3));

request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();

// this is the line of code that it eventually quits on.  
// Works fine for small files, not for large ones
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length); 

dataStream.Close();

//This will return "OK" if successful.
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Console.WriteLine("++ HttpWebResponse: " +
                  ((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
```

Comment: This might be obvious but are you sure Amazon's S3 service is allowing HTTP requests longer than 100MB?

Comment: I don't think this is the problem.  The full 100mb never gets sent (it stops after a minute or two).  I can send the file using any of the 3rd party S3 software programs and they send it via a PUT request and it works fine.  I think there is something wrong with my code other than a problem with S3.

Comment: In the code above, your timeout is just 6 minutes, not 30.

Comment: The timeout that I use when I create the S3 PUT URL is 30 minutes.  The URL link expires after 30 minutes.  The timeout in my code is for a connection timeout and that is set to 6 minutes.  The timeout is not the problem as the large file transfers never even hit the 6 minute mark.

Comment: What if you write in chunks to the dataStream? Does it always fail after certain number of bytes have been transferred?

Comment: I updated the error that is returned from the code:  The request was aborted: The request was canceled. at System.Net.ConnectStream.InternalWrite(Boolean async, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) at System.Net.ConnectStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)

Comment: Are you running this via ASP.Net or regular desktop?

Comment: @RonaldWildenberg:  You were right.  It was the .Timeout.  I changed it to a huge number and the file was transferred successfully.  I thought the timeout was a timeout if the WebRequest had trouble connecting to the server (timeout/retry).  I didn't realize it was a timer used to actually stop the transfer if it was exceeded.  Can you please turn yours into an answer so I can mark it as correct?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the [`Timeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.timeout.aspx) property of the [`WebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) to a higher value. It causes the request to time out before it is completed.

Comment: Thank you so much.  That was the problem.  I assumed this was a connection timeout, not an actual timeout that stops the transfer when it is exceeded.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to compare what goes over the wire when it works (3rd-party tools) and when it doesn't work (your code)... once you know the differences you can change your code accordingly...

Answer (score 1):

I would try writing it in chunks and splitting up the byte array.  It may be choking on one large chunk.

Something like this:

```
        const int chunkSize = 500;
        for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.Length; i += chunkSize)
        {
            int count = i + chunkSize > byteArray.Length ? byteArray.Length - i : chunkSize;
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, i, count);
        }
```

May want to double-check that to make sure it wrote everything, I only did very basic testing on it.

Comment: @fraXis done.  Change chunk size to whatever you feel's appropriate, maybe like 8KB or something, 500 bytes was just an example.

Answer (score 0):

Just a rough guess, but shouldn't you have:

```
request.ContentLength = byteArray.LongLength;
```

instead of:

```
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
```

Having second thought, 100 MB = 100 * 1024 * 1024 < 2^32, so it probably won't be the problem

Comment: That didn't have any effect.  Thanks anyways.