# WebRequest - .timeout question

Tags: c#, http, timeout, webrequest

For a little more background, please see:  [Problem with C# HTTP PUT request code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166237/problem-with-c-http-put-request-code)

I am using the C# WebRequest method to upload a file to S3.  I already have a pre-signed URL that S3 is giving me for the upload.  I originally had a problem where if I was uploading a large file, the transfer would stop a few minutes after starting.  A comment on my other post said it was the .timeout that was causing it.  Sure enough it was.

My question is this:  What should I set the .timeout to or how can I calculate what to set it do based on the size of the file that I am going to transfer?  
I don't want to start a WebRequest with a 60 minute timeout when I am only going to be sending a small file to S3, but then again I could also be uploading a gigabyte file to S3 also and if the timeout goes off before the file is done, the transfer will be interrupted.

Also how would I trap for a connection timeout?  Would the .timeout be used for that also?  What if I only want to try a connection for 30 seconds to see if S3 responds to my web PUT request and if doesn't then have it timeout.

My code is:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(PUT_URL_FINAL[0]);
//PUT_URL_FINAL IS THE PRE-SIGNED AMAZON S3 URL THAT I AM SENDING THE FILE TO

request.Timeout = 360000; //6 minutes -- If the transfer is over 6 minutes, it stops.

request.Method = "PUT";

//result3 is the filename that I am sending                                     
request.ContentType =
    MimeType(GlobalClass.AppDir + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "unzip" +
             Path.DirectorySeparatorChar +
             System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(result3));

byte[] byteArray =
    File.ReadAllBytes(
        GlobalClass.AppDir + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "unzip" +
        Path.DirectorySeparatorChar +
        System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(result3));

request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();

dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length); 

dataStream.Close();

//This will return "OK" if successful.
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Console.WriteLine("++ HttpWebResponse: " +
                  ((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
```

Comment: BTW, your `Stream` and `WebResponse` objects need to be within `using` blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try to calculate the timeout depending on your file size - but to do so means you must know or estimate some transfer speed...

Another option would be to choose your timeout in an "acceptable" for the usual cases and then when getting the exception retrying with double or ten times the "standard timeout"...